# Unable to Accept/Deny the location permission popup on Android devices while executing the scripts on Amazon Device Farm

Tags: cucumber, appium, aws-device-farm

[link of location popup image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2DXGC.jpg) I am trying to execute the automation scripts(Appium+Java+TestNG/Junit) on Amazon DeviceFarm but while executing, scripts were unable to perform any action((Access/Deny) on Location permission popup.Couldn't see any error logs in console. I have used normal click() operation as well as alert() function. Nothing works in this case.

Please help me.Below is the piece of code that I have tried..

```
        WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(android, 5);
        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.alertIsPresent());
        driver.switchTo().alert().dismiss();
        }catch(Throwable t) {
            System.out.println("Not an alert popup or alert is not present..");
            driver.findElement(By.id("idofthelocator")).click();
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, `cap.setCapability(AndroidMobileCapabilityType.AUTO_GRANT_PERMISSIONS, "true");` did not work for me as well. So, I tried finding the locators of the pop-up as usual and then click on same and it worked like a charm. Could you also try finding the locators and clicking on the button as required. Below code works in my case:

```
`//Location service pop up
@FindBy(id ="com.android.packageinstaller:id/dialog_container")
public WebElement locationPopup;

//Location service allow button
@FindBy(id = "com.android.packageinstaller:id/permission_allow_button")
public WebElement locationPopupAllowButton;

WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(locationPopup));
locationPopupAllowButton.click();`
```

Hope it helps :)

Answer (score 0):

With Android Appium tests it should possible to dismiss permissions popups by setting the capability `autoGrantPermission` to true. This capability will evaluate the application for the permission it need and run and adb command to grant the app access. Here is the code in the Appium project that does that:

https://github.com/appium/appium-android-driver/blob/959e07d84dc9d09a11735872259ac87511d03b85/lib/android-helpers.js#L334

https://github.com/appium/appium-adb/blob/e6bdc234e7dcf61e0252aad3ac7ab47491fe3720/lib/tools/adb-commands.js#L186

Can you try this capability and let us know if that helps?

With iOS Appium tests the capability autoGrantPermission does NOT work with Appium version less then 1.9.1 because there's not way through Apple APIs to predict the permission necessary or accept them. A workaround is to either find the element manually by printing the page source and checking for it on the fly or use the following lines to take advantage of the selenium methods:

```
driver.switchTo().alert().accept();
driver.switchTo().alert().dismiss();
```

In the more recent versions of Appium changes were made to use the autoGrantPermission capability valid with iOS tests. Here is the PR for that request

https://github.com/appium/appium-xcuitest-driver/commit/f5267acab3bc9285161397fa19a8daf60ae0c6ae

Can you let us know which Appium version you're using in this case and provide some of the Appium server logs from the run in Device Farm and your local execution?

Comment: Hey @jmp,

Thanks for reply..

I have already tried using that capability 

`cap.setCapability(AndroidMobileCapabilityType.AUTO_GRANT_PERMISSIONS, "true"); `

But It didn't work.. I am clueless how I will be able to solve this issue.. I will share the logs by executing the same script again..

Comment: Any update? If my answer helped at all please mark it as correct

Comment: Hey sorry @jmp for the delayed reply, I have added the location popup image (in the form a link) .. Sometimes turning off the GPS  on devicefarm works but not always .. It worked two times out of 10..  If we launch the device by turning off the device it won't show the location permission popup but this is not working for every execution..

Comment: No worries, it certainly some permission pop-up. Can you share the appium server logs by chance?

Comment: The capability autograntpermissions should have worked there. The appium server logs should show the error if there is one.